# File Upload Not Work PHP

Tags: php

I have two file upload field .my first field file upload successfully but second file not.But In database all file name store correctly.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btnportfolio']))
{
             $picture_name1 =time().'-' .$_FILES["picture1"]["name"];

             $picture_name2 =time().'-' .$_FILES["picture2"]["name"];


    $c->setImage_one($picture_name1);

    $c->setImage_two($picture_name2);


                if($c->Insert())
                                {


                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["picture1"]["tmp_name"], "Slideshow/" . $picture_name1);                                 
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["picture2"]["tmp_name"], "Slideshow/" . $picture_name2);                                 


                                    print '<div class="alert alert-success">Insert Successfully</div>';

                                    $c = new Slideshow();
                    ?>
                                         <script>setTimeout('top.location = \'?a=slideshow\'', 500);</script>
                    <?php
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    print '<span>'.$c->getErr().'<span>';   
                                }           
}

?>
```

Here Is My Html Form Code

```
        <div class="form-group">
             <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Image Item One</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
                    <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Select file</span>
                    <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span>        
                     <input type="file" name="picture1" id="picture1"/></span>
                    <span class="fileupload-preview"></span>
                    <a href="#" class="close fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload" style="float: none">×</a>
                  </div>  
            </div>
        </div>





        <div class="form-group">
             <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Image Item Two</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
                    <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Select file</span>
                    <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span>        
                     <input type="file" name="picture2" id="picture2"/></span>
                    <span class="fileupload-preview"></span>
                    <a href="#" class="close fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload" style="float: none">×</a>
                  </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
```

I cant understand why only one file uploaded.I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

you need form tag with

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

</form>
```

Comment: Already added if I am forgot to add it then one picture item can's uploaded

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the php.ini . `max_file_uploads` might need to be set.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php